# Error 2007 I cannot call a class variable on main timeline by using other class variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, events, listener

I'm creating an inventory system and it almost works. There are two objects on my scene which are 'apple' and 'pear'. You can see their names when you MOUSE_MOVE on them. You can click on them and they disappear and their icons appear on inventory.

What I need is to see itemName when I MOUSE_MOVE on items too. As I did with objects themselves. But I cannot set an eventListener on apple.itemIcon or pear.itemIcon and call the itemName in the function. I just don't know what to write. I had many problems with Events, Listeners and BaseClasses/Classes, some things in AS3 are really hard to understand for me.

This is my main timeline code: (This code gives Error2007 because of empty text in showItemNameG)

```
//INVENTORY
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import inventory.inventorySystem;
import inventory.itemC;
import flash.text.TextField;

var IS:inventorySystem = new inventorySystem();
var IT:itemC;
var itemNameBox:String;

apple.itemName = "Apple";
apple.itemIcon = new AppleIcon();
apple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, showItemNameF);
apple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideItemNameF);
apple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUpItem);

function showItemNameG(e:MouseEvent):void{
    itemNameBox = itemC(e.currentTarget).itemName;   <<<<
    stage.addChild(infoBoxObject);
    infoBoxObject.infoBox.text = itemNameBox;
    infoBoxObject.x = mouseX+12;
    infoBoxObject.y = mouseY;
}

pear.itemName = "Pear";
pear.itemIcon = new PearIcon();
pear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, showItemNameF);
pear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideItemNameF);
pear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUpItem);

function pickUpItem(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var index = IS.addObject(itemC(e.currentTarget));
    itemC(e.currentTarget).x = -145;
    itemC(e.currentTarget).y = 61;
    addChild(itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon);
    itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon.x = 38.15+(index*64);
    itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon.y = 340.65;
    itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, showItemNameG);   <<<<
}

function showItemNameF(e:MouseEvent):void{
    itemNameBox = itemC(e.currentTarget).itemName;
    stage.addChild(infoBoxObject);
    infoBoxObject.infoBox.text = itemNameBox;
    infoBoxObject.x = mouseX+12;
    infoBoxObject.y = mouseY;
}

function hideItemNameF(e:MouseEvent):void{
    infoBoxObject.x = -145;
    infoBoxObject.y = 61;
}

//CURSOR

Mouse.hide();
var cursor:cursorImage = new cursorImage();
stage.addChild(cursor);
cursor.startDrag(true);
```

This is my inventorySystem class:

```
package inventory{

    public class inventorySystem{

        private var slot:Array;
        public function inventorySystem(){
            slot = new Array(10);
            for(var k=0; k<10; k++){
                slot[k]=null;
            }
        }

        public function addObject(it:itemC):int{
            for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
                if(slot[i]==null){
                    slot[i] = it;
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        public function getObject(i:int):itemC{
            return slot[i];
        }

        public function useObject(i:int){
            slot[i] = null;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my itemC class:

```
package inventory{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class itemC extends MovieClip{

        public var itemName:String = "AJBHAKB";
        public var itemIcon:MovieClip;

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Solution to this was to give icons 'item' as base class. Then I had to name them when they are added to the stage. For this, I only changed pickUpItem function like this:

```
function pickUpItem(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var index = IS.addObject(itemC(e.currentTarget));
    itemC(e.currentTarget).x = -145;
    itemC(e.currentTarget).y = 61;
    addChild(itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon);
    itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon.x = 38.15+(index*64);
    itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon.y = 340.65;
    itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon.name = itemC(e.currentTarget).name+"Icon";
    itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, showItemNameF);
    itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideItemNameF);
    itemC(e.currentTarget).itemIcon.itemName = itemC(e.currentTarget).itemName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `showItemNameG` listener to a wrong object, you should add it to an object of `itemC` instead of adding it to a child movie clip. If you truly must do this, call their `parent` property, which, given your `itemC` class file, will be the direct child of an `itemC`.

```
function showItemNameG(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var ic:itemC=e.currentTarget as itemC;
    if (!ic) ic=(e.currentTarget as DisplayObject).parent as itemC;
    // here, first say current target is a DisplayObject, then get parent and coerce type
    if (!ic) {
        // oops! neither parent nor current target is itemC
        trace(e.currentTarget,(e.currentTarget as DisplayObject).parent);
        return;
    }
    itemNameBox = ic.itemName;  // process "ic" as the detected item
    stage.addChild(infoBoxObject);
    infoBoxObject.infoBox.text = itemNameBox;
    infoBoxObject.x = mouseX+12;
    infoBoxObject.y = mouseY;
}
```

Comment: Well, firstly thanks for trying to help me out. I tried your code and it gave me AppleIcon as target and Timeline as parent. Still I needed to point AppleIcon without giving the specific name. And then I came up with the idea of changing icons' base classes to 'item' and edited function as you can see in my main post.

Comment: Good thing you've come to a solution. So, you were adding the icon itself, not the `itemC` instance to the stage, that's why you couldn't reach the item. The better way is to contain all the item management in the `itemC` class, including listeners, and add the `itemC` instances to stage instead of adding icons, and add icons to `itemC` instances to provide visuals for the item. You can of course stick with your approach.

Comment: Well, yes probably the best solution is to make icons' classes 'item' also because it creates lots of call issues. I really need more time with AS3 'cause many things are still not clear in my mind. I can find solutions but I can't code them basically. Thanks again.